# Prevent gnome power manager from showing keyboard battery

Tags: gnome, bluetooth, power-management, battery

My gnome toolbar shows a battery indicator which is always wrong. I recently figured out why; as when clicked it shows both my internal battery status and my keyboard status as two separate items:

[image]

However the main display that I can see most of the time amalgamates these:

[image]

This just caused me to lose work as my laptop battery was critical and I got no warning because the keyboard battery is fine. I'd like the power manager to ignore the keyboard, but whilst seeing various bug reports and patches to disable the device battery triggering shutdown/suspend procedures, there's little on the hopefully smaller issue of just not showing it in the toolbar.

Here's my output of `$ upower -d`

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 15 Sep 2015 10:35:06 BST (566 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                LNV-45N1
  serial:               1336
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 15 Sep 2015 10:44:21 BST (11 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              4.59 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         47.52 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47.52 Wh
    energy-rate:         21.069 W
    voltage:             10.872 V
    time to full:        2.0 hours
    percentage:          9%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1442310231  9.000   charging
  History (rate):
    1442310261  21.069  charging
    1442310231  21.086  charging
    1442310201  21.245  charging
    1442310171  21.237  charging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_hid_90o7fo61o11o30o28_battery
  native-path:          hid-90:7f:61:11:30:28-battery
  model:                ThinkPad Compact Bluetooth Keyboard with TrackPoint
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Tue 15 Sep 2015 10:44:31 BST (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          60%
    capacity:            100%

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   yes
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

As we can see, the battery `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_hid_90o7fo61o11o30o28_battery` is the one that needs to be ignored. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: could you post a picture of your system settings with the power settings open? Make sure your keyboard is on and showing in the bottom. Thanks!